# Change or completely overload component styles in Angular 4

Tags: css, angular

In Angluar 4 application I have a component with this metadata:

`styleUrls: ['comoponent-name.css'],`

Is there a way to tell Angular to ignore all CSS rules in this style and apply new rules from some other file (or string)?

- dynamically (let's say upon a button click event)
- upon app build (based on some condition, ex. `this.variable = 'stylename'`)

Comment: you always can create your .css like .class1 h1{color:red}; .class2 h1{color:green} and enclosed your component in a < div [ngClass]="clase" >